# Pipeline works differently

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I'm a bit stuck. Why this pipeline returns nothing

```
Get-Content -Path C:\file.json | ConvertFrom-Json | Where-Object -Property FullName -Like "*somefilter*"
```

But when I split in into two pipelines it acually returns what I want - content of the json file (which is an array of objects) filtered by FullName

```
$t = Get-Content -Path C:\file.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$t | Where-Object -Property FullName -Like "*somefilter*"
```

Comment: Looks similar to [ConvertFrom-Json pipeline mystery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842781). Could you post a JSON file example?

Comment: `Get-Content -Path C:\file.json |ConvertFrom-Json |Write-Output |Where-Object ...`, see: [`#3424` ConvertFrom-Json sends objects converted from a JSON array as an *array* through the pipeline.](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3424)

Comment: Yes. Thanks. It is definitely a duplicate. Just didn't figured out how to google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a know issue which is described here: [`#3424` ConvertFrom-Json sends objects converted from a JSON array as an array through the pipeline.](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3424) and [Powershell calling Github API: ConvertFrom-Json pipeline mystery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842781/powershell-calling-github-api-convertfrom-json-pipeline-mystery):

```
$Json = @'
[
  {
    "FullName": "a"
  },
  {
    "FullName": "b"
  },
  {
    "FullName": "c"
  }
]
'@
```

**Issue**

```
$Json |ConvertFrom-Json |Where-Object -Property FullName -Like 'a'
```

Returns nothing because in the older version of [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) sends an array (as a single item) through the pipeline rather separate items:

```
($Json |ConvertFrom-Json).Count # returns 1 (in older versions of PowerShell)
```

As a workaround, you might simply [unroll the pipeline items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28702588/1701026) using [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output):

```
$Json |ConvertFrom-Json |Write-Output |Where-Object -Property FullName -Like 'a'

FullName
--------
a
```

The issue is resolved in newer PowerShell (core 7.x) versions.